# Apache Spark: Iterate rows of dataframe and create new dataframe through MutableList (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am currently trying to learn working with Apache Spark in Scala.

I have the following table as dataframe I want to use for analysis

[image]

Now I'd like to iterate through the rows, get the id and the count of words of the string in the body column and output the information in a dataframe with 2 columns.

```
def analyseDF(df:DataFrame): Unit = {
      //var retFrame = spark.emptyDataset[ClassIdCount].toDF()
      var tList = mutable.MutableList[IdCount]()

      df.foreach(row => {
        val wordCnt = row.getString(5).split(" ").size
        val mailid = row.getString(0)

        val record = IdCount(mailid.toString(), wordCnt.toInt)
        tList += record

        println(tList)
        println(record)

      })
      tList.toDF().show()
     // tList.toDS().show()

    }
```

Somehow on calling tList.toDF().show(), the frame with the 2 columns is always empty, but the records in the loop are generated correctly. Anybody can give me a hint here?

Answer (score 2):

typical beginner mistake: `tList` only lives on the driver, it cannot be updated from the executor-side code. Thats not how you create a dataframe from an existing dataframe. Use transformations/aggregation instead.

In you case you can do it with build-in Dataframe API functions `split` and `size`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val transformedDf = df
  .select(
      $"id",
      size(split($"body"," "))).as("cnt")
  )
```